# Combining multiple Local-SSD on a node in Kubernetes (GKE)

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

The data required by my container is too large to fit on one local SSD. I also need to access the SSD's as one filesystem from my container. So I would need to attach multiple ones. How do I combine them (single partition, RAID0, etc) and make them accessible as one volume mount in my container?

This link shares how to mount an SSD https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/persistent-volumes/local-ssd to a mount path. I am not sure how you would merge multiple.

**edit**

The question asks how one would "combine" multiple SSD devices, individually mounted, on a single node in GKE.

Comment: Please read the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page, since unless you are prepared to accept "Yes" as an answer, this is a terrible question

Comment: Please explain what procedure are you following? What is your plan to do exactly?Or Are you getting any error messages? Providing more information can help us to pinpoint the issue and then community can provide you best answer.

Comment: Sorry about that. Edited the description. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 6):

> **WARNING** 
>   this is experimental and not intended for production use without
>   knowing what you are doing and only tested on gke version 1.16.x.

The approach includes a `daemonset` using a `configmap` to use `nsenter` (with wait tricks) for host namespace and privileged access so you can manage the devices. Specifically for GKE Local SSDs, we can unmount those devices and then raid0 them. InitContainer for the dirty work as this type of task seems most apparent for something you'd need to mark complete, and to then kill privileged container access (or even the Pod). Here is how it is done.

The example assumes 16 SSDs, however, you'll want to adjust the hardcoded values as necessary. Also, ensure your OS image reqs, I use Ubuntu. Also make sure the version of GKE you use starts local-ssd's at sd[b]

**ConfigMap**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: local-ssds-setup
  namespace: search
data:
    setup.sh: |
        #!/bin/bash
        # returns exit codes: 0 = found, 1 = not found
        isMounted() { findmnt -rno SOURCE,TARGET "$1" >/dev/null;} #path or device

        # existing disks & mounts
        SSDS=(/dev/sdb /dev/sdc /dev/sdd /dev/sde /dev/sdf /dev/sdg /dev/sdh /dev/sdi /dev/sdj /dev/sdk /dev/sdl /dev/sdm /dev/sdn /dev/sdo /dev/sdp /dev/sdq)

        # install mdadm utility
        apt-get -y update && apt-get -y install mdadm --no-install-recommends
        apt-get autoremove

        # OPTIONAL: determine what to do with existing, I wipe it here
        if [ -b "/dev/md0" ]
            then
            echo "raid array already created"

            if isMounted "/dev/md0"; then
                echo "already mounted - unmounting"
                umount /dev/md0 &> /dev/null || echo "soft error - assumed device was mounted"
            fi

            mdadm --stop /dev/md0
            mdadm --zero-superblock "${SSDS[@]}"                
        fi

        # unmount disks from host filesystem
        for i in {0..15}
        do 
            umount "${SSDS[i]}" &> /dev/null || echo "${SSDS[i]} already unmounted"
        done

        if isMounted "/dev/sdb";
            then 
            echo ""
            echo "unmount failure - prevent raid0" 1>&2
            exit 1
        fi

        # raid0 array
        yes | mdadm --create /dev/md0 --force --level=0 --raid-devices=16 "${SSDS[@]}"

        echo "raid array created"

        # format 
        mkfs.ext4 -F /dev/md0

        # mount, change /mnt/ssd-array to whatever
        mkdir -p /mnt/ssd-array
        mount /dev/md0 /mnt/ssd-array
        chmod a+w /mnt/ssd-array

    wait.sh: |
        #!/bin/bash
        while sudo fuser /var/{lib/{dpkg,apt/lists},cache/apt/archives}/lock >/dev/null 2>&1; do sleep 1; done
```

**DeamonSet pod spec**

```
spec:
      hostPID: true
      nodeSelector:
        cloud.google.com/gke-local-ssd: "true"
      volumes:
      - name: setup-script
        configMap:
          name: local-ssds-setup
      - name: host-mount
        hostPath:
          path: /tmp/setup
      initContainers:
      - name: local-ssds-init
        image: marketplace.gcr.io/google/ubuntu1804
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
        volumeMounts:
        - name: setup-script
          mountPath: /tmp
        - name: host-mount
          mountPath: /host
        command:
          - /bin/bash
          - -c
          - |
            set -e
            set -x

            # Copy setup script to the host
            cp /tmp/setup.sh /host

            # Copy wait script to the host 
            cp /tmp/wait.sh /host

            # Wait for updates to complete
            /usr/bin/nsenter -m/proc/1/ns/mnt -- chmod u+x /tmp/setup/wait.sh

            # Give execute priv to script
            /usr/bin/nsenter -m/proc/1/ns/mnt -- chmod u+x /tmp/setup/setup.sh

            # Wait for Node updates to complete
            /usr/bin/nsenter -m/proc/1/ns/mnt /tmp/setup/wait.sh

            # If the /tmp folder is mounted on the host then it can run the script
            /usr/bin/nsenter -m/proc/1/ns/mnt /tmp/setup/setup.sh
      containers:
      - image: "gcr.io/google-containers/pause:2.0"
        name: pause
```

Answer (score 3):

For high performance use cases, use the [Ephemeral storage on local SSDs](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/persistent-volumes/local-ssd#creating_a_node_pool_using_ephemeral_storage_on_local_ssds) GKE feature. All local SSDs will be configures as a (striped) raid0 array and mounted into the pod.

Quick summary:

1. Create the node pool or cluster with the option: **--ephemeral-storage local-ssd-count=X**
2. Schedule to nodes with **cloud.google.com/gke-ephemeral-storage-local-ssd**.
3. Add an **emptyDir** volume.
4. Mount it with **volumeMounts**.

Here's how I used it with a DaemonSet:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: myapp
  labels:
    app: myapp
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: myapp
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myapp
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        cloud.google.com/gke-ephemeral-storage-local-ssd: "true"
      volumes:
      - name: localssd
        emptyDir: {}
      containers:
        - name: myapp
          image: <IMAGE>
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /scratch
              name: localssd
```

Comment: today, in 2022, this would be my preferred approach as well

Answer (score -1):

You can use [DaemonSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/daemonset/) yaml file to deploy the pod will run on startup, assuming already created a cluster with 2 local-SSD  (this pod will be in charge of creating the Raid0 disk)

```
kind: DaemonSet
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: ssd-startup-script
  labels:
    app: ssd-startup-script
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: ssd-startup-script
   spec:
     hostPID: true
     containers:
     - name: ssd-startup-script
    image: gcr.io/google-containers/startup-script:v1
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    securityContext:
      privileged: true
    env:
    - name: STARTUP_SCRIPT
      value: |
        #!/bin/bash
        sudo curl -s https://get.docker.com/ | sh
        echo Done
```

The pod that will have access to the disk array in the above example is “/mnt/disks/ssd-array”

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
 name: test-pod
spec:
 containers:
- name: test-container
  image: ubuntu
  volumeMounts:
  - mountPath: /mnt/disks/ssd-array
   name: ssd-array
  args:
  - sleep
  - "1000"
nodeSelector:
 cloud.google.com/gke-local-ssd: "true"
tolerations:
- key: "local-ssd"
 operator: "Exists"
 effect: "NoSchedule"
volumes:
- name: ssd-array
  hostPath:
   path: /mnt/disks/ssd-array
```

After deploying the test-pod, SSH to the pod from your cloud-shell or any instance.

Then run :

```
  kubectl exec -it test-pod -- /bin/bash
```

After that you should be able to see the created file in the ssd-array disk.

```
cat test-file.txt
```

Comment: So basically the startup script will include the scripts in the link I provided right?

Comment: Actually, I do not find startup script that include scripts in the provided link. But you can increase the ssd# for every local SSD you want as part of the raid array.

Comment: where exactly do you create the array?